# Should I move Node.js to a separate server, or host it together with LNMP?

Tags: vps, node.js

I wanted to add some features to my site which would require using Node.js over websockets. So my options are:

1. Install Node on a separate VPS;
2. Install Node on the same server where my websites are.

Let's say the main server has enough resources to handle both MySQL, Nginx & PHP (about 10 websites) and Node. At the same time, getting one more VPS isn't a problem either.

My initial concern was not being able to make Node listen on common ports like 443 (which are less likely to be firewalled on user's end), but I can make Nginx, which is already listening on that port, proxy the corresponding requests to Node, so that's not that big of an issue.

I looked through [Apache and Node.js on the Same Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server), [Node.js apps and wordpress on the same vps](https://serverfault.com/questions/443167/node-js-apps-and-wordpress-on-the-same-vps), as well as [this search results page](https://serverfault.com/search?q=node.js+vps), but those mostly cover the actual setups, and not the reasoning behind choosing them.

It feels like getting an additional VPS is somehow a more reliable, *cleaner* idea, but I might be wrong, so I'm asking for your advice on the arguments to justify getting an additional VPS.

Comment: This is too opinion based, imo. That said I'm a huge advocate of one role per server.. If you are using Nginx _just_ to proxy to node it's one thing.. If you are doing more it's something else.

Comment: @TimBrigham I agree, I wanted to keep them separate myself, I just needed arguments to justify that to my clients. Let me actually edit the question to highlight that.